# How do a get a function to recognize a return value from other function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I started learning to code recently, and following a program called Odin Project. I'm currently tring to make a Rock, Paper Scissor games, but I got stuck. I created a function to to make the computer choose a random value among the three options and return one of them. Then I created another function to alert a different message according to the computerchoice. But I always get the message "Something went wrong", which means this new function is not getting any of the correct options from the previous one. Can anybody help?

```
// THIS FUNCTION DECIDES IF THE COMPUTER CHOOSES ROCK, PAPER OR SCISSOS
function getComputerChoice () {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    if (rand <= 3) {
        return "Rock"
    } else if (rand <= 6) {
        return "Paper"
    } else {
        return "Scissors"
}}

// I PUT THE COMPUTER CHOICE FUNCTION IN A CONST BOX
const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();

// TESTING PLAYROUND FUNCTION
function playRound(computerSelection) { 
        if (computerSelection === "Paper") {
        alert("You lose! Paper beats Rock")
    } else if (computerSelection === "Rock") {
        alert("Draw")
    } else if (computerSelection === "Scissors") {
        alert("You win!")
    } else {
        alert("Something went wrong")
    }
  }
   
   

function game() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) {
        // your code here!
        playRound();
     }
}

game();
```

Comment: `playRound(computerSelection )`

Comment: You didn't pass any value to `playRound` which means `computerSelection` (the parameter) is undefined.

Comment: Either pass a parameter to `playRound` or remove the parameter from the function definition so it doesn't shadow the global variable of the same name.

Comment: You need to pass the return to the other function

Answer (score 0):

Move the line `const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();` into the function `playRound()` and get rid of the parameter of that function:

```js
// THIS FUNCTION DECIDES IF THE COMPUTER CHOOSES ROCK, PAPER OR SCISSOS
function getComputerChoice() {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  if (rand <= 3) {
    return "Rock"
  } else if (rand <= 6) {
    return "Paper"
  } else {
    return "Scissors"
  }
}


// TESTING PLAYROUND FUNCTION
function playRound() {
  // I PUT THE COMPUTER CHOICE FUNCTION IN A CONST BOX
  const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
  if (computerSelection === "Paper") {
    alert("You lose! Paper beats Rock")
  } else if (computerSelection === "Rock") {
    alert("Draw")
  } else if (computerSelection === "Scissors") {
    alert("You win!")
  } else {
    alert("Something went wrong")
  }
}



function game() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    // your code here!
    playRound();
  }
}

game();
```